# Is there a built in way of efficiently finding if a vector is in a vector array and if so what # variable it is

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am creating a procedurally generated cave generation script and I have gotten down all the perlin noise garbage out of the way and am trying to transform the vertices into a mesh . I understand that I need to declare the faces for it and need some form of marching cubes algorithm. For me to know which direction to render the face in I need my script to be aware of all the vertices around it by searching through the vertices. Is there any way my script can efficiently search through a vector3 array to find if a vector3 is in there and if so what place in the array is the Vector3 in?

Comment: `array.IndexOf(vector)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a triangulation lookup table based implementation of marching cubes, you could store a normal vector alongside the face in the same table entry. A video by Sebastian Lague mentions using such a table. I'm not exactly sure where he downloaded it from, but he includes it in his repo which is MIT licensed. [Video](https://youtu.be/M3iI2l0ltbE?t=102), [Table](https://github.com/SebLague/Marching-Cubes/tree/master/Assets/Scripts/Compute/Includes) (EDIT: The order of a triangle's vertices alone may be sufficient to define its direction, and you may not need an explicit normal vector)

Also heads up: Old Perlin noise tends to be visibly grid aligned. Most times I see it used, appear to be because a library provided it or because it was mentioned in a tutorial, and not because it was actually the best choice for the application. Simplex-type noises generally produce less grid-aligned results. It's straightforward to import external noise into Unity. It looks like you might need to anyway, if your implementation depends on 3D noise. [Here are the noises from my repo that use an open implementation for 3D, a tailored gradient table, and rotated evaluators that are good for terrain](https://github.com/KdotJPG/OpenSimplex2/tree/master/csharp). There are a lot of other options out there too, though they may not have these aspects in particular. Note that the range is [-1,1] not [0,1] so if your current noise is [0, 1], you might need to do noise(...) * 0.5 + 0.5 to correct that. Choose the 2F version if you have a lot of octaves, or the 2S version if you have one octave or are doing ridged noise.